# Python requests session cannot store response cookie from 302 redirect

Tags: python, python-requests

I am attempting to use requests to login to a website and store an authentication cookie for future browsing.

I send a POST request to login.aspx with my username & password.
In Chrome login.aspx correctly gives a set-cookie response header and then a 302 redirect to anotherpage.aspx.

In requests I am simply not able to see the 'set-cookie' header in the login.aspx response. Do you have any ideas?

I have tried turning off auto-direct in the request line. This changes the status_code to 302 but the set-cookie header does not appear.

```
import requests
s = requests.Session()

url = 'https://website.com/login.aspx'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0', 'Referer': 'https://website.com./login.aspx?'}

payload = {'UserName': 'USERNAME',
           'Password': 'PASSWORD',
           'LoginButton': 'Login',
           }

r = s.post(url, headers=headers, data=payload)

print(r.cookies.get_dict())
# >> {}

print(r.history[0].url)
# >> https://website.com/login.aspx

print(r.history[0].cookies.get_dict())
# >> {}

print(r.cookies.get_dict())
# >> {}

print(r.url)
# >> http://website.com/anotherpage.aspx

print(r.status_code)
# >> 200
```

Comment: Cookies are stored in the `session` object, so you should have some cookies in`s.cookies`

Comment: print(s.cookies.get_dict()) shows only one session ID cookie (from before login) but not the cookie I want that's provided after a successful login..

Comment: Do you see more cookies in your browser? Do you have all the required items in `payload` and `headers`?

Comment: I know 2 years passed, but were you able to solve it? Running in the similar problem right now :)